# Passing variable from react-router to child components

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

How to pass variable  to child components from react-router on server side.
I want pass some variables to my components which rendered by RoutingContext

```
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
import { match, RouterContext } from 'react-router'
import routes from './routes'

serve((req, res) => {
  match({ routes, location: req.url }, (error, redirectLocation,     renderProps) => {
    if (error) {
  res.status(500).send(error.message)
    } else if (redirectLocation) {
  res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search)
    } else if (renderProps) {
  res.status(200).send(renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps} />))
    } else {
  res.status(404).send('Not found')
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same issue with trying to add custom props to render props.

I found this link really useful:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/2073

Note: see comment before last

---

If I understand what you mean in your comment -- you need a way of passing your server data to your client side component.

I tend to render it out using EJS (or whatever templating language you are using in express) to assign the JSON string into a script tag in the HTML and assign it to the window scope.

So your index.ejs file would look contain something like

```
<body>
    <main>
        <%- markup %>
    </main>

    <script>
        window.data = JSON.parse('<%- data %>');
    </script>
</body>
```

Then in your server js

```
var customProps = {}; // the data you are passing in
var markup = renderToString(...); // your renderToString stuff you did before

var data = {
    markup: markup,
    data: JSON.stringify(customProps)
};

res.status(200).render(index.ejs', data);
```

Then in your top level route you can reference `window.data`*

- Note: you'll need to add in some condition to know whether you're using browser or server, I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-browser

Comment: thank you very much!it works but i have a new problem...i am rendering this data from server.but client side router doesnt see the data which i am renderin og server with component....

Comment: please help i am stuck

Comment: Did this help at all? ↑

Comment: sorry i will check it in the evening.but is it normal way to pass data to window object?
is-browser is for browserify.but i am using webpack.hm i think webpack have same module.but can you explain why i have to use this?will i use this on server ?or client?

Comment: If you are using react "Isomorphically" your application needs to run both on the server and the client. Therefore you need a way of passing your initial props to your client rendered code. I'm sure there are alternative ways to do this, but the simplest way I have found is via window object.

The isbrowser module, is a simple module that, when required, will tell you whether it is being ran on the sever || client, via it's package.json. I'm sure if it doesn't work in browserify there will be an alternate.

Can be used like:

    `var props = require('is-browser') ? window.props : this.props;`

Comment: but do you know another ways to pass props from server to client?

Comment: Window is how I have used it yeah, but you could use a data attribute of a dom element or something. Either way it needs to be in your html render really unless you want to re-request your data source from your server via ajax or something which would kind of defeat the point of doing it on the server. There may well be better solution out there, without seeing your full setup it's hard to say. I suggest having a look at existing examples and tutorials on the subject, there are a lot.

Comment: did you see this example?
https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit
i think it works without window object

Comment: thank you OllieH!it works.but i want to find best solution for this problem.because if data from server is big i think it is not right to send it to window object